# Getting Blank Values while extracting data from list of JSON in String column using AWS Athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table with below columns and data types.

```
id string
name string
title string
listItems string
```

**purchase_list table:**

| id | name | title | listItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Peter | Purchase List | [{"manufacture_date":"2023-01-01","purchase_price":"20.0"}, {"manufacture_date":"2023-01-02","purchase_price":"30.0"}] |

**Query used:**

```
with raw_data as
(
select 
      id
    , name
    , title
    , json_parse(listItems) as listItems
from purchase_list
)
select 
      id
    , name
    , title
    , json_extract_scalar(listItems,'$.manufacture_date') as manufacture_date
    , json_extract_scalar(listItems,'$.purchase_price') as purchase_price
from raw_data
```

**Expected output:**

| id | name | title | manufacture_date | purchase_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Peter | Purchase List | 2023-01-01 | 20.0 |
| 123 | Peter | Purchase List | 2023-01-02 | 30.0 |

When I extract data using json_extract_scalar, I am getting blank values

| id | name | title | listItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Peter | Purchase List |  |

Please advise how I can achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`json_extract_scalar` works with scalar values, arrays are not scalar values and your paths do not account for array in the JSON.

One way to handle this is to cast your JSON to array of JSON and unnest:

```
-- sample data
with dataset(listItems) as (
    values ('[{"manufacture_date":"2023-01-01","purchase_price":"20.0"}, {"manufacture_date":"2023-01-02","purchase_price":"30.0"}]')
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(item, '$.manufacture_date') as manufacture_date
    , json_extract_scalar(item, '$.purchase_price') as purchase_price
from dataset,
unnest(cast(json_parse(listItems) as array(json))) as t(item);
```

Output:

| manufacture_date | purchase_price |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 20.0 |
| 2023-01-02 | 30.0 |

Alternatively you can dabble with Trino's [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-query):

```
-- query 
select json_query(
                 listItems,
                 'lax $[*].manufacture_date'
                 WITH ARRAY WRAPPER
                ) AS dates,
    json_query(
                 listItems,
                 'lax $[*].purchase_price'
                 WITH ARRAY WRAPPER
                ) AS prices
from dataset;
```

Output:

| dates | prices |
| --- | --- |
| ["2023-01-01","2023-01-02"] | ["20.0","30.0"] |

Which can also be processed with `unnest` (i.e. `unnest(json_query(...), json_query(...)) as t(manufacture_date, purchase_price)`)